# Could not find plugin in Tizen Web Simulator

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-web-simulator

I am using Samsung Tizen SDK 2.4 and I have created a project for Samsung Tizen smart tv. When I am running project run as Tizen Web Simulator application (Samsung TV). It is running but my video is not playing and it's giving error **could not find plugin**.

Comment: have you fond solution or this issue still there

Answer (score 0):

The simulator does not support all features like download or USB  and does not give satisfying results in other features like watching videos. when I was using simulator, sometimes just refreshing the project on simulator works fine.
Though I recommend you work with emulator, it gives more satisfying results and it is much more closer to a real TV.

The documentation from https://www.samsungdforum.com/tizenguide/tizen2911/index.html is the best way to learn how to do that.
Hope this will help.

Comment: I am also want to use Emulator but when I start  Emulator then Emulator is showing a black  blank screen. After deploy project again emulator is showing black blank screen. can you explore me how can I use Emulator. Tzen SDK version is 2.4.

Comment: Have you tried to run a sample app from Github https://github.com/SamsungDForum/AVPlaySample ?
Otherwise, if you can share your index.html, main.js and config.xml files, I may be able to help you